# Identifying unique pairs of values from two columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like the following:

```
myDf <- data.frame(Var1 = c("dennis", "marcus", "bat" ,"man", "mennis", "cool"), 
                   Var2 = c("mennis", "cool", "man", "bat", "dennis", "marcus"))

> myDf
    Var1    Var2
1 dennis  mennis
2 marcus    cool
3    bat     man
4    man     bat
5 mennis   dennis
6   cool   marcus
```

What I would like to achieve is a unique pair from both the variables, such as follows:

```
    Var1    Var2
1 dennis  mennis
2 marcus    cool
3    bat     man
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We `sort` by row using `apply` with `MARGIN=1`, get a logical index using `duplicated` and then subset the original dataset based on that.

```
 myDf[!duplicated(t(apply(myDf, 1, sort))),]
 #    Var1   Var2
 #1 dennis mennis
 #2 marcus   cool
 #3    bat    man
```

Comment: thanks so much, don't know why this never came to my mind for almost half a day... Kudos to you, and 'boos' to me! :)

Comment: @info_seekeR  It may be a bit tricky to think about it.  I guess it is a legitimate question, but it may have been asked before.